# How can I track tweets from a particular city and store in a MongoDB via python?

Tags: python, mongodb, twitter, location, pymongo

I would like to write a piece of code that grabs all tweets from a particular location (e.g. a city) and puts them in a MongoDB via python. As a complete newcomer to programming, I have managed to track particular hashtags from Twitter and store them in MongoDB using the following piece of code:

```
01 import pycurl, json
02 import pymongo
03
04 STREAM_URL = "https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json"
05 WORDS = "track=#occupywallstreet"
06 USER = "myuser"
07 PASS = "mypass"
08
09 def on_tweet(data):
10    try:
11        tweet = json.loads(data)
12        db.posts.insert(tweet)
13        print tweet
14    except:
15        return
16

17 from pymongo import Connection
18 connection = Connection()
19 db = connection.occupywallstreet
20 conn = pycurl.Curl()
21 conn.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
22 conn.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, WORDS)
23 conn.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ["Connection: keep-alive", "Keep-Alive: 3000"])
24 conn.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, "%s:%s" % (USER, PASS))
25 conn.setopt(pycurl.URL, STREAM_URL)
26 conn.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, on_tweet)
27 conn.perform()
```

How can I track for geolocated tweets, i.e. tweets from a particular city? Is there a way that I may alter the above code to suit my needs?

Thanks!

Comment: FULL DISCLOSURE: the code used is taken from: http://gramsky.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/how-to-use-twitters-filtered-streaming.html

Comment: when you get json of a tweet check it's lat long in bounding box of a city if they are withing bounding box then save tweet to db

Answer (score 1):

You should use [locations](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters#locations) parameter in this case:

```
import pycurl
import json

STREAM_URL = "https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json"
LOCATIONS = "locations=-74,40,-73,41"  # New York
USER = "myuser"
PASS = "mypass"


def on_tweet(data):
    try:
        tweet = json.loads(data)
        db.posts.insert(tweet)
        print tweet
    except:
        return


from pymongo import Connection

connection = Connection()
db = connection.occupywallstreet
conn = pycurl.Curl()
conn.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
conn.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, LOCATIONS)
conn.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ["Connection: keep-alive", "Keep-Alive: 3000"])
conn.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, "%s:%s" % (USER, PASS))
conn.setopt(pycurl.URL, STREAM_URL)
conn.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, on_tweet)
conn.perform()
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, this works well. However, it very quickly racks up the GB's. Is there a way of getting the data in a more compact format?

Comment: Well, first you can get only necessary data from a tweet in `on_tweet` function. Also, think about what tweets do you really need to store in the database, I bet you don't really need all of the tweets from the specified location. Consider accepting the answer if it helped. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. Is there a way to only store tweets with a given hashtag from that location, e.g."#Yankees" from LOCATIONS = "location=-74,40,-73,41" (New York)?

Comment: Not sure that your code works now after deprecation of 1.0 twitter API. Consider switching to 1.1, see https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets.

Comment: Hmm... as a beginner with all things programming, I am not sure I understand your answer. Could you expand on your previous answer, i.e. what would be the best way to grab tweets from a given location without racking up the GB's? And then: is this answer related to twitter 1.0 API or 1.1 API? Thank you for being so pedagogical.

Comment: Yeah, this code doesn't work right now (though worked a couple of weeks ago). I'd suggest to use `python-twitter` or `tweepy` python libraries for working with twitter api.